# Redirect URI is lost in multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I do multiple ajax calls in my application amyapp.mydomain.com/func1

1) There is a call made to a different site to fetch some data. It redirects for an entry token:

```
$.ajax(
    .
    url: siteA.domainA.com/action1,
    .
)
```

which gives a 302 response to get a token from siteB.domainA.com/getToken.

2) Now, other parts of page loads and another ajax call is made to my own application like below

```
$.ajax(
    .
    url: amyapp.mydomain.com/func2,
    .
)
```

3) Now, when the 1st ajax call handles redirection, its request params are set as

```
redirect_uri: amyapp.mydomain.com/func2
```

instead of

```
redirect_uri: siteA.domainA.com/action1.
```

This causes siteB.domainA.com to throw `error 400`

However, if I do not make the 2nd ajax call until (1) completes, there is no error. How could I correct this? I tried using latest jQuery version as well.

Edit (Pasted Code):

Inside `func1.html`:

```
function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
}
var ajax_request = {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url, // siteA.domainA.com/action1
    data: my_args,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: setHeader
};
var request = $.ajax(ajax_request);
var handler = function(data) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Actions based on data
    });
};
request.done(function(data) {
    handler(data);
});
request.fail(function(data) {
    handler(data);
});
```

Inside `common.html` which is extended by `func1.html`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: https://amyapp.mydomain.com/func2,
       success: function (data) {
            if(data === "ABC"){
                $('#ABC').html('Dummy');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Post your code. I think you have to use callbacks to not jumbled the redirect

Comment: you can call the second_ajax_function inside first_ajax_function callback.

Comment: The ajax functions are coming from different html files and I cannot merge them. I do use separate success handler functions for both. I don't think I can post the actual source code, but I will post a one which behaves similarly

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to make sense of this, not with the minimal snippets you have shown. There is no obvious reason why two completely different AJAX requests would “mix” their parameters in that way. _“Now, when the 1st ajax call handles redirection”_ - that happens automatically anyway, so there is not even a point were you _could_ deliberately change the request parameters even if you wanted to. We need a proper [mcve] for this.

Comment: Hope the snippets help. I will try to give a working mcve example. I have just obfuscated the urls in above example